# Should Application logic have access to repositories?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

With DDD approach in mind, I'm moving a class to a common folder, as it's going to be shared between modules. The problem is that I can't figure how to make it work with Dependency Injection and a container.

Basically, MenuService generate method, creates an instance of autogenerator passing 4 arrays from the MenuRepository;

**MenuService.php**

```
namespace MP\Application\Services;

use MP\Domain\Repositories\Repository;
use MP\Application\Generation\AutoGenerator;

class MenuService {

    private $repository;   

    public function __construct(Repository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function generate(){
        // fetch/set $recipes, $menu, $settings;
        $generate = new AutoGenerator($recipesArr, $menuArr, $allIngredients);
    }
}
```

The only reason for `$allIngredients` being passed here is because AutoGenerator instantiates another class named Scaler, the main method is called `scale($recipe, $percentage, $AllIngredients)` which is the only place `$allIngredients` is even used in the autogenerator class.

```
class AutoGenerator {
    public function add(...){
        $percentage = new Percentage(...); 
        $scaler = new Scaler();
        $try = $scaler->scale($recipe, $percentage, $this->allIngredients);

        if($try->isSuccess()){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove all this dependency with the MenuService to the AutoGenerator, and finally the Scaler... basically, I created class called Ingredients with the __invoke method which takes the repository in the constructor, it's instantiated early in the software and now I injected it in the constructor.

The problem is that AutoGenerator now can't instantiate the Scaler class because it has a constructor dependency, which means that the AutoGenerator class now has to pass the Scaler as a Dependency... which leads to my following issue.. where should I pass the $recipesArr, and $menuArr?

The reason why I'm asking is because I'm not sure if it's correct for me to have to create a class just to return a database query just so I can pass it in the constructor. The $recipesArr/$allIngredients comes from RecipeRepository, the $menuArr comes from MenuRepository;

Or should I just inject RecipeRepository and MenuRepository in the scaler constructor?

This is the folder structure:

```
MP\Application\Generation\Common\Scaler;
MP\Application\Generation\AutoGenerator;

SHARED\Domain\Repositories\Ingredients;

MP\Domain\Repositories\RecipeRepository;
MP\Domain\Repositories\MenuRepository;
```

Comment: In your question, you described the `solution` and are asking what is wrong with it. Instead, I'd describe `the problem` - the domain, and what are you trying to achieve. Then somebody may have an opinion on if the model is any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **yes**.

The application service is the one that should care about reading and persisting. The proper use is this:

1. based on some input (ID) you need to get a given domain entity
2. then via the other input parameters you call either a method/property on the entity or you use a domain service where you pass in your domain entities and new inputs.
3. the domain service (or the call on the entity) will do a change in the domain entities. these changes are still in memory.
4. so at the end you will need to persist those changes.

I've just googled a bit, so for more details check out this: https://blog.arkency.com/application-service-ruby-rails-ddd/